# NodeJS: Unable to write to Windows 8 block device

Tags: windows, node.js, block-device

I'm looking forward to write directly to a raw windows block device.

I can successfully do so with [dd for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd):

```
> dd.exe if=myData.dat of=\\.\PhysicalDrive1
```

However I'm unable to do so using NodeJS. I'm using [node-blockdevice](https://github.com/jhermsmeier/node-blockdevice/issues/1) in the following manner:

```
var device = new BlockDevice({
  path: '\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1',
  mode: 'w+',
  size: 512
});

device.write(0, myBuffer, callback);
```

`device.write` correctly returns the amount of bytes written, however it's not actually writing anything to the device.

Notice that the exact code works successfully in Mac OS X (substituting `\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1` with `/dev/diskN` of course): it writes my data and I can view it without any problem in Windows 8.

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried:

- Not escaping the backslashes (`\\.\PhysicalDrive1`) but that results in a `EINV` error.
- Using the logical name: `\\\\.\\E:`.
- Unmounting the volume with `mountvol X: /D` before attempting to read/write.

I can correctly confirm the id of the device I want to write to with:

```
wmic diskdrive list brief
```

I've also tried setting the `mode` to `rs+`. The read operation seemed to work, however the saved data contained the following failure-related data:

```
�X�MSDOS5.0�
�?����:�)?�xNO NAME    FAT32   3ɎѼ�{��ٽ|�V@�N�V@�A��U�r��U�u
��t�F�-�V@�s�����f��@f�р�?�����Af��f��f�F�~u9�~*w3f�Ff��
                                                        ����,���}��|���t<�t   ������}��}��ߘ��f`�~� fjfPSfh�B�V@���fXfXfXfX�3f;F�r��*f3�f�Nf����f��f���v�֊V@����
 ̸�fa�t���f@Iu��BOOTMGR
Disk error�
Press any key to restart
��U�%
```

**EDIT:** A github issue thread describing more things I've tried: https://github.com/jhermsmeier/node-blockdevice/issues/1.

**EDIT:** All approaches mentioned were tested with admin privileges.

**EDIT:** I'm using `device.close(callback)`, but omitted in the example for simplicity.

Comment: If the command works when called from command line, then you can run it without the `node-blockdevice` module altogether with [child process spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). If this approach does not work, then please update your question with content of `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak That'd require me to ship the dd for windows binary with my package, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694713/createfile-direct-write-operation-to-raw-disk-access-is-denied-vista-win7

Comment: And you successfully read the boot sector from the drive :)

Comment: @HansPassant I've read the same device's MBR on OS X, but it's different from the one I've read from W8.

Comment: check this link may help u https://github.com/jhermsmeier/node-blockdevice/issues/1

Comment: @DivyangShah I opened that issue myself, and also linked it in the question :)

Comment: oh, ok than ignore it.